# Flutter: How do I use the BatteryManager class inside this .jar file?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

On the Honeywell website they provided an Android SDK. I downloaded this SDK and imported the `.jar` file as a dependency in my project. I placed this file inside my project folder in `android/app/libs/Honeywell.jar`. How do I use the `BatteryManager` class? How would I do this in my `main.dart`?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reminder that asking for [tutorials is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That said you may want to go through the Flutter codelab on [How to write at Flutter plugin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/write-flutter-plugin?hl=en#0) and review [Flutter platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm not asking for a tutorial. I'll re-write the question to be more specific

Comment: If you are new to Android/Flutter, I would start with a Hello World Android app written in Java/Kotlin to access the Honeywell SDK methods. The doc if you scroll down appears to have an example. Once you understand what is required to get it working with Java/Kotlin then you can go through the links in my prior comment to get the Flutter side connected.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm not new to Flutter/Android/Android Studio. I have been working in this space for many years. I simply haven't ever worked with an external `.jar` file inside a Flutter project, so I just need someone to explain how to start using a `.jar` library inside Flutter.

Comment: Here is the thing. You can't "just put in a `.jar` file". Flutter is platform agnostic you will need to write a platform channel to hook it up. Flutter doesn't know what APIs exist on the native Java/Kotlin side which connects to the jar files APIs. If you had a iOS library you would need to do the same thing.

Comment: FYI the annoyance of creating binding between the Java to Dart side is being addressed by [jnigen](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/java-interop) but still experimental with open lssues like [Support implementing Java interfaces with Dart classes](https://github.com/dart-lang/jnigen/issues/70)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I actually found a flutter honeywell package that someone already wrote! And it works really well! Dropping it here for future readers: https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner. Thanks for all your help!